# laravel user list with posts and profile links

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I try to get list of all users with post and link them to different page where all their posts is listed.

Obviously I must make my list page first then my users detail page, but some how I ended up with detail page and no list page :)))

Anyway: this is what I have so far:

`Controller`

```
public function chef() {
      //
      return view('front.chef');
    }

    public function chefdetail($username) {
  $foods = Food::whereHas('user', function($q) use($username){
    $q->where('username',$username);
  })->get();
  return view('front.chef-detail', compact('foods'));
}
```

My routes:

```
Route::get('/chef/{username}', 'FrontendController@chefdetail')->name('chefdetail');
Route::get('/chefs', 'FrontendController@chef')->name('chefs');
```

**Questions (Problems) :**

1. How do I get list of users with posts in my `chef` function?
2. How do I add `username` to my chefs detail page URL

> Is it correct that I used `$user = User::find(1);` to getting users list? because I couldn't get users by id it returns error.

Comment: in the chefs page you need the posts too? or only in chef/username?

Comment: @LeonardoCabré no just name of users who has post and link to their detail page

Comment: you have a model for post?

Comment: yes, all model are related to each other.

Comment: @LeonardoCabré I updated my question in `chefdetail` function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With this code you pass all your users that have posts to your blade page

```
public function chef() {
  $users = User::has('posts')->get();
  return view('front.chef', compact("users"));
}
```

In your blade you can show them like:

```
@foreach ($users as $user) {
    <a href="{{ route("chefdetail",$user->username) }}">{{ $user->username }}</a>
@endforeach
```

then your chefdetail function should look like this:

```
public function chefdetail($username) {
  $user = User::where("username", $username)->with("posts")->first();
  return view('front.chef-detail', compact('user'));
}
```

and you can show the post like this:

```
@foreach ($user->posts as $post) {
    $post->someproperty
@endforeach
```

hope this helps you.

Comment: ok now there is 1 issue, in chef function it gets all users even those without post i want to get only users with posts.

Comment: Updated in answer